# Checkboxes states changing in kendo tree list while expanding and collapsing

Tags: angular, kendo-treeview

I have a checkbox template column in kendo tree list. When expanding or collapsing, the checkbox states are changing. For eg. If a row is checked, when i clicking on collapse and after that clicking on the expand the checked state is changed to unchecked.

I tried "autocomplete=off" in the checkbox template. But its not worked. And also i tried to remain its state in expand and collapse events of kendo tree list which was also not worked.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

KendoTree has never done anything for that part.

To solve this problem, you will keep a variable of the selected values and check the list when selecting this list and if it has been selected before.

> public checkedKeysTemp: any[] = [];

```
<kendo-treeview [nodes]="childData" [children]="children" [hasChildren]="hasChildren" [disabledKeys]="disabledKeys"  (checkedChange)="childCheckedChange($event)"
        textField="text" [kendoTreeViewCheckable]="checkableChildSettings" kendoTreeViewDisable [(checkedKeys)]="checkedKeys"
        [checkBy]="'table_rel_table_name'" [isChecked]="isChecked" kendoTreeViewExpandable>
      </kendo-treeview>
```

in ts file

```
childCheckedChange(event: any) {
...
}
```